# Choosing an appropriate window for a sliding average

Tags: python, statistics, data-science, data-analysis, sliding-window

I'm doing some statistical data analysis and I'm using a moving average to "cancel out" some noise! I was wondering if there is any process or a "right way" to determine the size of the window.

For example, in a specific data set, I have 22 883 data points over 90 seconds. What could be a good window size?

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: It depends of course on
1) the scatter level ("sigma") of your dataset
2) the target scatter level
I do not think anybody can set these levels in your stead.

Comment: And so to set it is just a matter of trial and error, where I just test some values until I get an output that I like?

Comment: I'd go for trial and error first, then if you want to have a systematic evaluation I'd measure the actual sigma and the target sigma, so that you set it once. Then the reduction should go roughly like
sigma_target/sigma_rawdata = 1/sqrt(win size)
and that's something you will be able to apply to new datasets, no need for another trial and error then (just measure again sigma_rawdata)

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much!